# Failed to decode downloaded font, but using correct CSS Font Face

Tags: css, fonts, shopify, font-face, google-fonts

I am using the following code to import the google Font "Syncopate" into my shopify site:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Syncopate';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0633/5778/0153/t/2/assets/Syncopate-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0633/5778/0153/t/2/assets/Syncopate-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0633/5778/0153/t/2/assets/Syncopate-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0633/5778/0153/t/2/assets/Syncopate-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0633/5778/0153/t/2/assets/Syncopate-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0633/5778/0153/t/2/assets/Syncopate-Regular.svg#Syncopate') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  }
```

I downloaded the .tff file from google fonts and created the font-face with transformer.org.
In the console of greenjet.at I now get the following errors:

- Failed to decode downloaded font (woff2, woff, ttf)
- OTS parsing error: Size of decompressed WOFF 2.0 is less than compressed size
- OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header
- OTS parsing error: FFTM: misaligned table

When implementing it with the google font link it works perfectly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Syncopate">
```

But it is necessary due to privacy issues with google to load the font locally.
What is the error here?
Is the shopify asset file uploader maybe using ASCII instead of the binary file transfer causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Otfs parsing errors usually indicate, your font files are not valid.**

The aforementioned font file is definitely corrupt/not valid

Your `@font-face` rules looks fine.

Although, transfonter is usually pretty reliable, you might have applied options (subsetting, metrics adjustments), that made the file structure invalid.

Instead of converting the master truetype files, try to get all font-files via [google web font helper.](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/syncopate).

Then try to upload/replace the font files.
Debugging: You should be able to download the new truetype font and doubleclick it in your Desktop environment (win, MacOs, Linux).
If your OS still bugging you about an invalid format - there's something wrong with the shopify uploader.

So you should contact the shopify support.
Maybe there's a bug in the file uploader (e.g. converting encodings).

Comment: you were right, there was a bug in the shopify uploader for theme assets. The support could not solve it right away, but when uploading the Font files at Settings > Files there was no error anymore! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add the code below, replacing highlighted elements of the code with actual data.

**Font name >** the name of the font. If the font has more than one word in its name, it will need "quotation marks";

**Filename >** the name of the file that was just uploaded to your theme including the file extension, for example, cosmic_sans_bold.ttf.

**Format >** the format of the font that was uploaded. For example, for Athena.ttf, this would be "TrueType".

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Font name";
    src: url({{ "Filename" | asset_url }}) format("Format");
}
```

Available font formats: "woff", "woff2", "truetype", "opentype", "embedded-opentype" and "svg".

Comment: Here is what I added: 
`@font-face {
    font-family: "Syncopate";
    src: url({{ "Syncopate-Regular.eot" | asset_url }});
    src: url({{ "Syncopate-Regular.eot" | asset_url }}) format('embedded-opentype'),
          url({{ "Syncopate-Regular.woff2" | asset_url }})  format('woff2'),
          url({{ "Syncopate-Regular.ttf" | asset_url }})  format('truetype'),
          url({{ "Syncopate-Regular.svg" | asset_url }})  format('svg');
  }`
I still get the same errors on www.greenjet.at in chrome browser

Comment: @ThomasDanninger are you Shopify admin for that site?

Comment: @ThomasDanninger can you please try the below format if you're an Shopify admin for that site.

Answer (score 1):

**Fonts in your theme**

**Non-admin**

Add the font files to the **assets** directory.

Create a `@font-face` CSS rule so that you can reference the font. Use the **asset_url filter** to output the URL for the font file:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Font name";
   src: url("{{ '[font-file-name]' | asset_url }}") format("[font-format]");
}
```

**Shopify admin**

Upload the font files to the **Settings > Files** section of the Shopify admin.

Create a `@font-face` CSS rule so that you can reference the font. Use the **file_url filter** to output the URL for the font file:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Font name";
   src: url("{{ '[font-file-name]' | file_url }}") format("[font-format]");
}
```

Comment: Yes I am an admin, I uploaded the files into the assets section of my theme and as you can see in the code above I added it with asset_url filter 
I tried adding the link directly as well instead of the liquid variable - not working
maybe the font file is corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify uploader corrupts the font files so to make fonts work, you will need to follow these steps:

1. Download the theme from the Shopify dashboard.
2. Unzip the theme and locate the font files.
3. Copy and paste the font files into the "Assets" folder in the unzipped theme folder.
4. Re-zip the theme and upload it back to the Shopify.
5. The font should now be working on the store.

If the fonts are still not working after following these steps, it is possible that the font files are corrupted.