# @font-face doesn't seem to be displayed, although it is being downloaded

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

Here's a website I'm working on: https://wolfies-whisky-ltd.myshopify.com (password: shooting)

I've used @font-face to load fonts that are being displayed fine - the RightGrotesk family. (I'm planning to add the WOFF & WOFF2 font files later, but as it's working for now, leaving it as it is.)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "RightGrotesk-CompactBlack";
    src: url("{{ 'RightGrotesk-CompactBlack.otf' | asset_url }}") format("opentype");
}
```

I'm using the exact same @font-face declaration for the body family, Modern Typewriter, but this one doesn't display. So, I've added all the possible formats.

```
/* Font declaration */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Modern Typewriter";
    src: local('Modern Typewriter'), url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/3933/3697/files/MODERNTYPEWRITER.eot?v=1694793617'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Modern Typewriter'), url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/3933/3697/files/MODERNTYPEWRITER.eot?v=1694793617?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
            url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/3933/3697/files/ModernTypewriter.otf?v=1694793617') format('opentype'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
            url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/3933/3697/files/MODERNTYPEWRITER.woff2?v=1694793617') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
            url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/3933/3697/files/MODERNTYPEWRITER.woff?v=1694793617') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
            url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/3933/3697/files/MODERNTYPEWRITER.ttf?v=1694793617')  format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* The CSS declaration that is taken into account */
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.06rem;
    font-family: "Modern Typewriter", Courier, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I've tried declaring font-style and font-weight, I've tried not declaring them. Using local(), or not. Different font formats, etc.

In the Inspect Element, if I click on the text where the font should appear, you can see it uses the body declaration further above, so it isn't being overwritten by a different class or parent element...

When checking the Network tab in the Inspector tools I can see it has been downloaded fine, status code 200.

[image]

So, I'm not really sure why it is not being displayed? At the moment it loads its fallback font, Courier, which means it's also reading the right CSS declaration, not one buried further down in another CSS file.

It does show up if I install the font locally on my computer, but that's not very useful.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant CSS, ie where  you are selecting that font?

Comment: Updated with the relevant CSS code. It's all in the <style> element on the index page, not in a external CSS file.

Comment: Please show the relevant CSS (not something that has to be pre-processed as we have no way of knowing what that is) or a snippet that has the font hardwired in with no CSS variables needed.

Comment: Thanks A Haworth, I've edited the question with the CSS that gets taken into account when the page loads.

Comment: Testing your site in a Chromium-based browser on Mac, the console is full of errors saying "Failed to decode downloaded font" and "OTS parsing error: OS/2: Failed to parse table", each occurring multiple times, and for all four variants (otf, woff, woff2, and ttf.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I'm not sure how I missed that. Will give it a deeper look.

Comment: I note that the font is being downloaded from shopify's system. Is that allowed? The website says: 'Note Personal access to the font files isn't currently available.' I don't claim to know what that means!

Comment: There seems to a bug in the shopif uploader (hopefully it was fixed). See also ['Failed to decode downloaded font, but using correct CSS Font Face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106922/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-but-using-correct-css-font-face/74115942#74115942)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's simply that the original font file (.ttf) is corrupted. Trying to convert it through Font Squirrel it says "The font 'modern_typewriter.ttf' is corrupt and cannot be converted."

So, there aren't any solutions, except using a different font, or somehow repairing this one, but I have no idea how (I've been looking at FontForge, but it seems like a new world that I'm not ready to explore).